# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException

Tags: sql, wpf, access

System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: "Отсутствует значение для одного или нескольких требуемых параметров."
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проблема решена? Дайте отклик

Answer (score 1):

Ох...

Во-первых, вы не задали вопрос. Stackoverflow - это сайт типа "Вопрос-ответ". Понимаете? В конце вопросительного предложения стоит знак вопроса.

Во-вторых, заголовок темы должен содержать суть.

В-третьих, код нужно приводить текстом, а не скриншотом.

В-четвертых, вы на каком языке пишете? Добавьте метку языка программирования. Удалите метку GUI-фреймворка, т. к. она не имеет отношения к вопросу.

---

Теперь главное. Я сильно подозреваю, что показанный текст исключения не относится к показанному на скриншоте коду. Нет в вашем коде параметров.

---

А теперь, собственно, ради чего я стал писать это сообщение. Я не могу пройти мимо такого быдлокода:

```
while (new OleDbCommand("...", db).ExecuteReader().Read())
```

Здесь создаётся объект `OleDbCommand`, создаётся объект `OleDbDataReader`, выполняется запрос в БД, возвращаются данные.
И если метод `Read()` будет успешен - хотя бы одна строка будет получена, - то цикл повторится: будет создан **новый** OleDbCommand, **новый** OleDbDataReader, будет выполнен **новый** запрос в БД, будут возвращены **те же самые** данные с начала.

Перепишем код следующим образом:

```
string query = "SELECT DISTINCT Специальность FROM Подразделения";

using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, db))
using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Но я повторю, что в sql-запросе нет параметров, следовательно текст исключения не относится к нему.

Comment: возможно проблема с русскими наименованиями объектов к базе. можно заключить их в квадратные скобки: SELECT DISTINCT [Специальность] FROM [Подразделения]

Comment: @Konst - ах, вот в чём дело. Я почти не знаком с Access.